# Caching a page where the header shows user details

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

We have a website that is using CodeIgniter and is using the full page caching technique:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

The problem we have is on the main header (navigation) of the website we either have (login/register) buttons or if the user has logged in we show the picture of the user with his/her name and a dropdown to edit profile and logout.

The cache right now caches the information generated by the user who activated it and therefore even if you are logged in or not it shows that.

How does one achieve caching a page but display some areas according to sessions?

I understand "ajax" is one way of achieving it, but is there another way? A more correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a more granular caching system, which caches whole templates and/or content-blocks, whatever form they may have. That is a task for the framework and cannot be achieved by webserver caching, because caching on the webserver/proxy level only caches whole pages and is usually determined by mime type. As soon as you have dynamic content, the cached website has to be free of any user-dependent content.

The best solution, as you already mentioned, is ajax. If the user is a guest, you can flatout deliver a cached page, because those pages aren't depending on user-identification. As soon as the user is logged in, I recommend disabling caching completely (you can do that with apache2 environment vars, which can be set according to a logincookie being present for example) or you deliver a static, cached "skeleton" page and re-load the user-content after the page reload.

Or you don't refresh the first page request at all and re-load all user content per ajax like facebook does for example.